# Django: time_threshold

Tags: django, timezone

I want to filter all the tickets which have been created within the last 15min. I use therefore the following code. I now wonder. If the people are in different timezones, will the way I wrote it here still work the way I intended (every ticket within the last 15 minutes, no matter which timezone)?

For created in my models I use `models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)`.

```
time_threshold = timezone.now() - timedelta(minutes=MINUTES_TICKET_RESERVATION)

        # Check ReservedItems
        reserved_items_qty = ReservedItem.objects.filter(
                ticket__id=ticket_id,
                created__gt=time_threshold,
            ).aggregate(
                Sum('quantity')
            )
```

Comment: If your project is timezone aware, yes: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/timezones/

Comment: Perfect, thank you Willem!